# Bind a client's local IP through SSL

Tags: c, openssl

I'm looking to add SSL support to a client application written in C/C++ that I'm developing (it is multi-platform, designed to work on Linux and Windows). OpenSSL documentation is pretty poor, but I found a good working tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html). To my knowledge, however, there is no way to bind the socket to a local IP address using the BIO handle. There is a rather old ticket on the OpenSSL bug tracker that addresses this, but I think that no solution has been found (one comment suggests using `BIO_get_accept_socket`, but that will obviously not work for my client application). Any suggestions, solutions, or alternative libraries that offer this kind of functionality?

Comment: That ticket is here: http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=480&user=guest&pass=guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create, bind and connect the socket yourself, then use `SSL_set_fd` to pass the socket to OpenSSL, followed by `SSL_connect` to set up the session.